# Cypress - AssertionError: expected [ { payload: { data: [Object] } } ] to have property 'TotalMessageUI_ObjectClicked'

Tags: json, cypress, assertion, nested-properties

I'm trying to verify `TotalMessageUI_ObjectClicked` contains a value other than NULL or 0

But I keep getting this error:

> AssertionError: expected [ { payload: { data: [Object] } } ] to have property 'TotalMessageUI_ObjectClicked'

What is the best way to verify `TotalMessageUI_ObjectClicked` contains a value not NULL

```js
{"data":{"actor":{"account":{"nrql":{"results":[{"TotalMessageUI_ObjectClicked":6}]}}}}}
```

Tried writing this:

```js
expect(response.body).have.property('TotalMessageUI_ObjectClicked').to.not.be.oneOf([null, "",0])
```

Answer (score 4):

The message

> AssertionError: expected [ { payload: { data: [Object] } } ] to have ...

is telling you that `response.body` (the object you supplied) is actually `[{ payload: { data: [Object] } } ]`.

So you can amend your test with that info, for example:

```js
expect(response.body[0].payload.data.actor.account.nrql.results[0].TotalMessageUI_ObjectClicked)
  .to.not.be.oneOf([null, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not drilling down to the correct prop in your expected result.

```
expect(response.body[0].payload.data.actor.account.nrql.results[0])
  .have.property('TotalMessageUI_ObjectClicked')
  .to.not.be.oneOf([null, "",0])
```

Comment: Makes sense, but when I drilled down further, even with your code I get an error at 'actor'
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'actor')`

Comment: Also the response is also a Payload, not sure if that is affecting it too. I tried
`expect(response.body.payload.data.actor.account.nrql.results[0]).have.property('TotalMessageUI_ObjectClicked').to.not.be.oneOf([null, "",0])` but same issue still too.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Comment: Looks like `response.body` is an array. You can try with `response.body[0].payload.data.actor.account.nrql.results[0]`.

Comment: Nice I updated the answer to reflect that.